# Dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have two dropdowns in my site. I want to change the number of options and the values of options of one dropdown depending on the value we choosing on the other dropbox by 'onChange()' fn using JavaScript. For example
/*first dropdown*/

```
<select name="language" id="language">
    <option>select</option>
    <option >English</option>
    <option>Tamil</option>
    <option>Telugu</option>
    <option >Kannada</option>
    <option>Malayalam</option>
    <option >Urdu</option>
    <option>Punjabi</option>
</select>
```

/*Second dropdown whose no of options & values are to be changed based on changing the value*/      /*of above dropdown*/

```
<select name="media">
    <option>The Indian Express</option>
    <option >The Hindu</option>
    <option >CNN IBN</option>
    <option>NDTV</option>
</select>
```

I was struggling with it for a long and even if this can be done through php please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

HTML

```
<select name="language" id="language" onchange="SetMedia(this)">
    <option>select</option>
    <option >English</option>
    <option>Tamil</option>
    <option>Telugu</option>
</select>

<select name="media" id="media" disabled="disabled">
    <option>select</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
function SetMedia(objLanguage) {
    var objMedia = document.getElementById("media");
    objMedia.options.length = 0;
        objMedia.disabled = false;
    switch (objLanguage.value) {
    case "English":
        objMedia.options.add(new Option("The Indian Express"));
        objMedia.options.add(new Option("The Hindu"));
        break;
    case "Tamil":
        objMedia.options.add(new Option("Tamil Paper 1"));
        objMedia.options.add(new Option("Tamil Paper 2"));
        break;
    case "Telugu":
        objMedia.options.add(new Option("Telugu Paper 1"));
        objMedia.options.add(new Option("Telugu Paper 2"));
        break;
    default:
        objMedia.options.add(new Option("select"));
        objMedia.disabled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/z48dc/

Comment: It's working but if i try to use another javascript fn()(jquery) to style the dropdown it ain't working. Also thanks for the above solution.

Comment: please elaborate.i did not get you.

Comment: Here i'm trying to use both the dropdowns by onchange and trying to add some stylish look to these dropdowns. Your code works fine when i use the dropdown without any styles but that doesn't a problem, being a starter i can't figure out how i can make the second dropdown too work by onchange method. I tried but failed to do so. I want both the dropdowns to be working by onChange.

Comment: Also i got a doubt. Is this possible to add values too for the options while creating second dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do this just plain javascript than you can do this.Which will result in little dirty approach .

http://www.felgall.com/jstip22.htm

I would suggest to do this using JQUERY and AJAX . Send a AJAX request to get the second dropdown data . Check this sample

http://www.99points.info/2010/06/ajax-tutorial-dynamic-loading-of-combobox-using-jquery-and-ajax-in-php/

http://demos.99points.info/dynamic_dropdown/