# Add or remove dropdown elements from the javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have dropdownlist whose value is filled using the value of the other drop down. The problem here is that i need to bind the value of the second when the value of the first changes. I need to do it from the javascript. 
Only thing i need to do is remove and add the select options in the second dropdown as the first dropdown changes. 
How can i do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you have, or preferably set up a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: can you show a little example code

Comment: I will explain with an example.  I have 2 dropdowns. 1 for showing the country and other for displaying the states. When the country in the 1st dropdown changes, i have to fill the second dropdown with the states in that country. This is an example. Actually i need to bind a secondary status using the primary status dropdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054187/dynamic-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure exactly what you want with the limited information provided but here is a solution that I think you are looking for:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="primary">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>    
</select>
<select id="secondary"></select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var opts = {
    'one':['a','b','c'],
    'two':['d','e','f']
};

$('#primary').change(function(){
    var select = [];
    $.each(opts[this.value], function(k, v){
        select.push('<option>'+ v +'</option>');            
    });
    $('#secondary').html(select.join(''));          
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/28TQZ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropdownlist1").change(function () {
    var selected = $("#dropdownlist1 option:selected");
    //clear
    $("#dropdownlist2").html("");
    $("#dropdownlist2").append($("<option/>").text(selected.text()).val(selected.val()));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create all the drop downs you need, but only add options to the first one. The next ones only have a "default" value.
- On selecting the first drop down, you use jQuery to get the values for the second drop down, based on the value selected in the first drop down:
  $.post('ajax/aj_populate2nddropdown.php', $("#firstdropdown").val(), function(result) {
  $('div.placedaround2nddropdown').html(result);
  });
- The file ajax/aj_populate2nddropdown.php collects the values of the second drop down, and returns them, inserted as options into the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it is to just have a main dropdown and a bunch of secondary dropdowns that start hidden.  when you choose something from the first, then you unhide the related second one

Comment: thank you for your reply TMP. But it creates a space in the design so that i could not use it.

Comment: you could just have a default second one that is empty or just refers back to the first one

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/triplecombo.shtml) If you are trying at client side

Replace your controls with asp.net server controls