# InfoWindow content change dynmically only some portion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I created markers using googlemap v3 and also make infowindow on click event on marker i display 2 `dropdown`, `input field` and `button` now i want to change the `value` of 2nd `dropdown` on the basis of `1st index change event`
Here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/6vVQq/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054187/dynamic-dropdown)

Comment: You should add your code to your question, not just link to an external site. If that page ever changes this question becomes redundant and useless for anyone else

Comment: @Dr.Molle i dont think so that its duplicate i knew how to change dropdown dynmaically i am asking about infoWindow content dynmically change

Comment: @duncan the external link is `jsfiddle` link and here when i put all code then it says too much code you post so i create live fiddel for the code

Comment: @SpookyMindz: it doesn't matter where the elements are placed inside the document, as long as they are a part of the DOM you may access and modify them. There is no need to access or modify the content-property of the infoWindow

Comment: @Dr.Molle ok now i understood before that i was a little bit confused
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of your question and after read your comments (about you know how to change data dynamically)
i suggest you have to add some id in this portion

```
var contentString = 
        '<div id="infowindow">\
            '+locationType+' <br />\
            '+LocationClass.locationSubType+' <br />\
            '+inputField+' <br />\
            '+saveBtn+' <br />\
        </div>';
```

like this

```
var contentString = 
        '<div id="infowindow">\
            '+locationType+' <br />\
            <span id="dynmaicContent"></span> <br />\
            '+inputField+' <br />\
            '+saveBtn+' <br />\
        </div>';
```

and after that you are able to change data as you want